# Missing required parameter for [Route: info.update] [URI: info/{info}] [Missing parameter: info]

Tags: php, laravel

In my web.php

```php
Route::resource('info',InfoController::class);
```

In my view

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('info.edit',$info->id) }}" role="button">Update</a>
```

In my URL
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/info/36/edit`

When i try to access the route info.edit trows error that is Missing required parameter for [Route: info.update] [URI: info/{info}] [Missing parameter: info].

So i try add manual the route like

```php
Route::get('/info/{info}/edit', [InfoController::class, 'edit'])->name('info.edit');
```

But throws the same error every time

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes. You should use `route('info.edit', ['info' => $info->id])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel automatically creates several routes for CRUD operations on the specified resource. It would have created a route named `info.update` that requires the info parameter to be passed in the URL. Try something like

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"
href="{{ route('info.edit', ['info' => $info->id]) }}"role="button">Update</a>
```

and make sure that the Route::resource (web.php) defines all the necessary routes for your InfoController resource

```
Route::resource('info', InfoController::class);
```

should create

```
HTTP       Path               Action    Route Name
GET        /info              index     info.index
GET        /info/create       create    info.create
POST       /info              store     info.store
GET        /info/{info}       show      info.show
GET        /info/{info}/edit  edit      info.edit
PUT/PATCH  /info/{info}       update    info.update
DELETE     /info/{info}       destroy   info.destroy
```

Comment: i did php artisan route:list and it shows the routes  GET|HEADinfo/{info}/edit  info.edit › InfoController@edit

Comment: If you see the route GET|HEAD info/{info}/edit with the name info.edit in the output of php artisan route:list, it means the route is registered correctly.

Comment: The error message suggests that the update method of the InfoController is being called instead of the edit method when you try to access the info.edit route.